# MySQL - Computing average time difference between 2 closest records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cross-join

I have a table `access` that stores the time when an employee accessed the system and also when he logged out.

```
access_id int(11) -- PK, auto-generated
employee_id (11)
in_time bigint(20) 
out_time bigint(20)
```

What I need is the average time when the employee was out (in_time - out_time of the previous access of the employee) - *for all employees*.

What I managed so far:

I could manage to calculate the average for a single employee using this (rather complex) query

```
SELECT AVG (b.in_time - a.out_time) / 60000 AS avginminutes
FROM access a CROSS JOIN access b
WHERE 
    b.access_id = 
    (SELECT MIN(c.access_id)
    FROM access c
    WHERE c.access_id > a.access_id
    and c.employee_id = 1765708 )
AND a.employee_id = 1765708
AND  b.in_time - a.out_time != 0
ORDER BY a.access_id ASC;
```

My main question is, how can I modify this query such that it could calculate the average for all employees? I did not get anywhere on this, after spending much time.

Secondly (but not important) , is there a way the query can be simplified?

Sample data:

```
access_id|employee_id|in_time      |out_time
|1       |1765708    |1643720400000|1643727600000
|2       |1765708    |1643728200000|1643734800000
|3       |1765708    |1643735100000|1643738400000
|4       |4344524    |1646125200000|1646128800000
|5       |4344524    |1646129100000|1646134200000
|6       |4344524    |1646134800000|1646142000000
|7       |4344524    |1646149200000|1646156400000
```

MySQL version: `5.5`

Comment: Post a data sample along with desired output (as text)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @MatBailie Version added

Comment: @Zakaria Sample data added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(The average time when the employee was out) 
 = 
(MAX(out_time) - MIN(in_time) - SUM(out_time - in_time)) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
```

I.e.

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       (MAX(out_time) - MIN(in_time) - SUM(out_time - in_time)) / (COUNT(*) - 1) / 60000 avginminutes
FROM access 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Of course will fail or will produce NULL (depends on SQL mode) if there is only one row for some employee. In strict mode - adjust with according CASE.

Comment: `NULLIF(COUNT(*), 1)`?

Comment: @Akina this actually works! Although I get the error ` [1690] [22001]: Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range` . Also can I also tell it to check only if the end_time is in an particular interval and also if the diff is more than 0?

Comment: As the gap could be 0 - as it refreshes every 15 minutes - if continuously logged in - how can I not count these entries?

Comment: @user1583803 ```CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'N/A' ELSE (MAX(out_time) - MIN(in_time) - SUM(out_time - in_time)) / (COUNT(*) - 1) / 60000 END avginminutes```

Comment: @Akina This though only handles the cases where there is only 1 row? In my case there could be many rows for the same employee, but the start time will be equal to the end time of the prev record and thereby the gap will be zero. I do not want to calculate entries where this diff is 0.

Comment: @user1583803 *This though only handles the cases where there is only 1 row?* This handles ALL cases.

Comment: @akina The op is materially changing their requirements; if the events progress as `(1,3)` then `(4,6)` then `(6,8)`, the second 'gap' is 0 seconds long and should be ignored (as this is implicitly a side effect of the system recording the state every 15mins, regardless of whether the state has changed).  Thus, there is only one remaining 'gap' of one second (4-3), and so the average 'gap' should be 1.

Comment: @user1583803 Material changes to the question, such as this, are discouraged on stackoverflow, as they invalidate preexisting answers. Please open a new question with *all* the necessary details relating to your revised requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8 you can use `LAG` function to find previous out time for each row:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        LAG(out_time) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY in_time) AS prev_out,
        in_time
    FROM t
)
SELECT employee_id, AVG(in_time - prev_out)
FROM cte
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Comment: Would have been nice, but the current version in us (5.5) doesn't support LAG :-(